# convert json ip address to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text / javascript";
  script.src = "http: //ipv4.myexternalip.com/json";
  var ip = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  alert(ip);
}
```

above code is giving run time error as  ':' in json causing syntax error so i am not getting anything to print. How to convert this json to string. I tried using `JSON.Stringify` but it returned only `{}`.

Comment: `':' in json causing syntax error`, should you not share sample JSON as well?

Comment: The `appendChild` method will return the element that you are appending, therefore in your example your `ip` variable is going to be the script element that you are creating.

Comment: I guess the issue comes from your JSON object...

Comment: {"ip":"203.91.213.179"} this is the json which i am getting